# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' - парсинг

Tags: python, парсер, tiktok

Цель программы: взять ссылку на последнее видео пользователя из **TikTok** и спарсить ее. Миллион раз сверил тег, класс, но возвращает `[]`. При выводе кода страницы исходного вообще не нахожу.

Вот мой код:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.tiktok.com/@dava_m?'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36/(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.95"}
r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
cards=soup.find('a',class_='jsx-1906445185 video-feed-item-wrapper').get('href')
print(cards)
```

Прикрепляю скриншот пути к файлу:

[image: Скрин пути]

Comment: Какое то время код успешно парсил ссылку, а потом начал выводить None

Comment: глупый вопрос: можете написать шаблон поиска? уже второй час сам пытаюсь, не понимаю абсолютно

Comment: либо же просто подсказать